# Replying to other email

Tags: email, phpmailer

I'm building webmail with `PhpMailer`.
I need advice about replaying to other email.

How to attach previous email? Should I simply attach it as a file - I think it's not good.

I prefer attach email text, but how? Using only `blockquote`? But what about previous mail's styles? I see in thunderbird `blockquote` with `cite="mid:hash"` attribute. What is it?

Maybe `PhpMailer` has some options regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally pretty straightforward. [Read this](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) about how to deal with the headers (use `addCustomHeader` to set them) so that mail clients can identify it as a reply.

There's no particular standard for what to do with the body, though it's common to copy all the lines of the original body into the new message, preceded by `>`, though you could wrap it in a blockquote in HTML, or some other formatting. It's up to you what you do with attachments.

Comment: Thanks very much - got it. I've added header and give blockqoute with text version of previous message with my style.